# Durandal and jquery mobile for swipe

Tags: jquery-mobile, swipe, durandal

I am using Durandal which is available in the Hot towel template SPA.
The idea is to have a SPA application for a touch based device, and I need to implement swipe feature on some on the divs.

jquery mobile supports swipe feature, but can someone tell me how to use it.
There is a data-bind on the div, where I give the 'swipe: somefuntion' - this does not happen, whereas the same works when I use a click instead of swipe. And somefunction is defined in the view model.

I have included the jquery mobile in the scripts and also in the bundle.

Can someone help me out if this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working eample: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/pf3kc/

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Share QR</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />   
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="article1">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <h1>Articles</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>Article 1</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <h1>Footer</h1>    
    </div>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).off('swipeleft').on('swipeleft', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){    
    alert('swipeleft');      
});

$(document).off('swiperight').on('swiperight', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){   
    alert('swiperight');           
});
```

Comment: This is a jQuery mobile swipe implementation, if you are using then you don't need to worry it will work.

Comment: I confirm it works with Durandal. I omitted the '[data-role-page]' business and I set up the event handlers in shell.js just before setting up routes.